# Cannot use python IPWhois: IPWhois instance has no attribute 'lookup_rws'

Tags: python, python3

I am following [an IPWhois example posted on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997623/how-to-parse-text-in-python-with-ipwhois). I am howfrom

```
ipwhois import IPWhois

obj = IPWhois('74.125.227.206')
results = obj.lookup_rws()
print(results['nets'][0]['name'])
```

I have however the following error when executing it:

```
# python ipwhois_.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipwhois_.py", line 4, in <module>
    results = obj.lookup_rws()
AttributeError: IPWhois instance has no attribute 'lookup_rws'
```

I am certain of having installed IPWhois properly.

**Why do I have this error?** (the script is working for others)

PS: I excecute it with python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lookup_rws` method has been removed as of version `0.11.0`.  The current version of `IPWhoIs` only has two non-deprecated methods: `lookup_whois` and `lookup_rdap`.

To install the last version of `IPWhoIS` that supported `lookup_rws` you will need to do something like:

```
pip install ipwhois==0.10.3
```